# Is there any way to get meta data from hive in hue?

Tags: hive, metadata, hiveql

I tried to get meta data in hue from hive but all failed.

Im looking for the way not using metastore in mysql.. etc or shell.

Information_schema is also not implemented in hive…

If i can get meta data, i wanna make a table about all meta data like table name, columns and type.

Comment: Sorry the info that information_schema cant be used in hive is wrong. That is an old ver.